# Flutter - Height of NavighationRail

Tags: flutter, user-interface

How can I shrink the NavigationRail in Flutter? I have a 140 pixel high Container but a NavRail with 3 Tabs needs approx 225 pixcel. If possible I do not want to resize my container.
I tried several different approaches (Colums, Containers, IntrinsicHeight, ...) but nothing worked.

```
class PATWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const PATWidget({super.key});

  @override
  State<PATWidget> createState() => _PATWidgetState();
}

class _PATWidgetState extends State<PATWidget> {
  int index = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(children: [
      Row(
        //Headline
      ),
      Row(
        children: [
          Column(
            children: [
              Container(
                height: 140,
                width: 30,
                child: NavigationRail(
                  selectedIconTheme:
                      IconThemeData(color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
                  unselectedIconTheme: IconThemeData(color: fumigruen_accent),
                  backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).scaffoldBackgroundColor,
                  labelType: NavigationRailLabelType.none,
                  selectedIndex: index,
                  onDestinationSelected: (index) =>
                      setState(() => this.index = index),
                  destinations: [
                    NavigationRailDestination(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.abc),
                      selectedIcon: Icon(Icons.pin_drop),
                      label: Text(
                        "",
                      ),
                    ),
                    NavigationRailDestination(
                      icon: Container(height: 20, child: Icon(Icons.abc)),
                      selectedIcon:
                          Container(height: 20, child: Icon(Icons.abc)),
                      label: Text(""),
                    ),
                    NavigationRailDestination(
                      icon: Container(height: 20, child: Icon(Icons.abc)),
                      selectedIcon:
                          Container(height: 20, child: Icon(Icons.abc)),
                      label: Text(""),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: buildPages(),
          ),
        ],
      )
    ]);
  }
```

[image: Pixeloverflow]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `minWidth` on `NavigationRail`.

```dart
Container(
  height: 140,
  width: 30,
  child: NavigationRail(
    minWidth: 140 / 3 - 8, // your value. -8 it has extra padding i belive 
    unselectedIconTheme: IconThemeData(
```